# Copiar arquivo com progresso

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arquivo

Como eu utilizo a função em C# `File.Copy(string path);` para copiar um arquivo incrementando um valor em uma **ProgressBar**?

Comment: Nathan, o suporte HTML no site é muito básico, prefira usar o Markdown: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa função não pode ser utilizada para mostrar progresso (ela basicamente chama a função nativa - Win32 API - `CopyFile` de kernel32.dll). Não há uma função na classe `File` que faça a cópia com notificação de progresso, mas você pode criar um `wrapper` (usando PInvoke) sobre a função nativa `CopyFileEx` da mesma biblioteca, como o descrito aqui: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CopyFileEx.

[A resposta a uma pergunta similar no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8341945/751090) tem uma implementação completa do wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

Achei uma implementação mais simples no SO na [resposta do Anton Semenov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6055385/221800).

```
public delegate void ProgressChangeDelegate(double percentage, ref bool cancel);
public delegate void CompleteDelegate();

class CustomFileCopier {
    public CustomFileCopier(string source, string dest) {
        this.SourceFilePath = source;
        this.DestFilePath = dest;
        OnProgressChanged += delegate { }; //só para facilitar o exemplo aqui
        OnComplete +=  delegate { }; //só para facilitar o exemplo aqui
    }

    public void Copy() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024]; // 1MB buffer
        bool cancelFlag = false;
        using (FileStream source = new FileStream(SourceFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
            long fileLength = source.Length;
            using (FileStream dest = new FileStream(DestFilePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write)) {
                long totalBytes = 0;
                int currentBlockSize = 0;
                while ((currentBlockSize = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
                    totalBytes += currentBlockSize;
                    double percentage = (double)totalBytes * 100.0 / fileLength;
                    dest.Write(buffer, 0, currentBlockSize);
                    cancelFlag = false;
                    OnProgressChanged(percentage, ref cancelFlag);
                    if (cancelFlag == true) {break; } // Delete dest file here
                }
            }
        }
        OnComplete();
    }

    public string SourceFilePath { get; set; }
    public string DestFilePath { get; set; }

    public event ProgressChangeDelegate OnProgressChanged;
    public event CompleteDelegate OnComplete;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/ProgressCopier.cs)

Dá para deixar mais completo. Terá que fazer a implementação da assinatura do evento, algo como:

```
(percentage, cancelFlag) => { if (OnProgressChanged != null)
                                  OnProgressChanged(percentage, ref cancelFlag); };
```

e

```
(percentage, cancelFlag) => { if (OnComplete != null)
                                   OnComplete(percentage, ref cancelFlag); };
```

É preciso rodar em outra *thread* e assinar o evento `OnProgressChanged` para receber as notificações de progresso da cópia.

Se você estiver utilizando o WinForms e quiser uma [barra de progresso pronta](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0) o .NET tem uma. Não sei se seria compatível com a classe acima. Não tive tempo de testar mas não vejo porque não. Você executaria o `PerformStep()` dentro do método que assina o evento `OnProgressChanged`.

Algumas outras opções (não quer dizer que eu as acho boas, nem ruins):

- http://hintdesk.com/c-wpf-copy-files-with-progress-bar-by-copyfileex-api/
- http://ronniediaz.com/2011/05/17/copy-file-with-update-progress-in-net/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36647/How-to-copy-files-in-C-with-a-customizable-progres

Answer (score 1):

Adiciona referência a biblioteca: Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

> (A DLL pode ser encontrado na pasta
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versão.net.xxx) Escolha a versão .NET
>   de acordo com o seu projeto

No código:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

...
{
   FileSystem.CopyFile(ArqOrigem, ArqDestino, UIOption.AllDialogs);
}
...
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Fonte:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687443/how-to-bring-up-the-built-in-file-copy-dialog

Comment: Sim mas estou usando C# não VB

Comment: E mesmo assim só tens isso: http://prntscr.com/9ko87h

Comment: Esse código é C#, adicione referência a DLL (Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll), procure na pasta:  ; `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versão.net.xxx` ex: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`